# If I connect to Facebook with an unconnected account will I lose my progress?

Tags: clash-of-clans

If I connect to Facebook I will overwrite/lose my current account? I want to save my account but I'm already an almost maxed out town hall seven.

Comment: It should give you an option to overwrite or not. **Disclaimer: I am not responsible if you lose your save data.**

Answer (score 1):

No, but it will save your current progress to that Facebook account.